How to output variable values from addeventlistener
let xc = null;
let yc = null;
var el = document.getElementById("canvas");

el.addEventListener('mousemove', function(f) {
  console.log('Coordinates: x=' + f.clientX + ' y=' + f.clientY);
  xc = f.clientX;
  yc = f.clientY;
  return xc;
  return yc;
})

console.log(xc, yc);

As a result, when you touch the screen, the coordinates are shown, but are not updated separately via console.log

Move the console log inside the event listener so it will run everytime the event is triggered.

Event listeners can't really return anything, but your variables are in the global scope, so you are able to update them from your event listener. You add your listener, but it doesn't run until the mouse is moved. You are logging them before they've actually been updated.
